# Accessing service in Startup class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to update the DB after a user logged in to my app (using fb) and I am not sure how to use the `DbContext` within startup.cs.

startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<mysiteContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(_configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddFacebook(options =>
        {
            options.AppId = "********";
            options.AppSecret = "*********";
            options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
            {
                var userFbId = context.User.Value<string>("id");
                string userProfileImageUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/{userFbId}/picture?type=large";

                //TODO: Save to DB infromation about the user and update last login date.   
                //This is where I am having the issue.
                UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();

                //Example how to add information to the claim.
                var surname = context.User.Value<string>("last_name");
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, surname));

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        })
        .AddCookie();
```

And my UserRepository.cs:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly mysiteContext _myDbContext;
    private readonly short _languageTypeId;

    public UserRepository(mysiteContext ctx)
    {
        _myDbContext = ctx;
        _languageTypeId = Language.GetLanguageTypeId();
    }
}
```

How can I pass `mysiteContext` to the `UserRepository` class?

Comment: You already passed it in constructor or not? Do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: You registered this services via 'dependency injection' in your Startup.cs so you can use it. Haven't you try run your code?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? I don't understand. What do you mean under "use it" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
services.AddScoped<UserRepository>(); // <-- Register UserRepository here

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddFacebook(options =>
   {
         options.AppId = "********";
         options.AppSecret = "*********";
         options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
         {
               ........

               ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
               var userRepository =  serviceProvider.GetService<UserRepository>();

               // Do whatever you want to do with userRepository here.

               .........

               return Task.FromResult(0);
          };
   })
```

Alternatively you can also get `UserRepository` instance from `context` as follows:

```
var userRepository =  context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserRepository>();
```

Comment: It works, but I am not sure about something.
Do I need to pass dbcontext from myController to myRepository every time or use this approach?
@KirkLarkin can you take a look at last image in chat please?

Comment: @OffirPe'er You don't need to pass dbconext from controller to repository. See the updated answer. You can also access the repository instance from context gracefully.

Comment: But I have many repositories, should I add them all as services? can you join the chat please?

Comment: @OffirPe'er of course! This is way of using services in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Do you know all this only based of docs.microsoft or do you have other resources?

Comment: Microosft documentation is good enough! They are the creator of this framework.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190351/discussion-between-offir-peer-and-tanvirarjel).

Comment: The only answer here is using the 'alternative' approach mentioned. BuildServiceProvider has potentially unintended  consequences as it will instantiate your singletons again, outside of the ones that are instantiates by your normal DI setup (ex AddSingleton)

Comment: @AdamTuliper it seems this is not recommended then. Any other suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use my Dapper service inside 'ConfigureServices' section, where 'context' is not available. The easiest way for me was to get the service via 'BuildServiceProvider':

```
IDapper _dapper = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDapper>();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for- its good for only a simple testing when the code is complex and hard to trigger specific flow, to just manually trigger it on startup.